# PowerShell Ftp upload

Tags: powershell, upload, proxy, ftp

```
$infographie="C:\Archive\Infographie\28052013\myfile.pdf"

$ftp = "ftp://174.9.102.210/public_html/infographie/myfile.pdf"

$user = "****"

$pass = "*******"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  

$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

try{

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $infographie) 

}
catch
{

Write-Host "`nAn Error occured while uploading file to: $Uri"

Throw    
}
```

I have problem each time, i try to execute the script, i've tried many solutions but none of them solved my problem

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during
a ebClient request."
At D:\Scripts\test.ps1:14 char:22
+ $webclient.UploadFile <<<< ($uri,$File)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

When i use filezila it seems to use Proxy ixftp.e-i.net:8011 and it works, i don't know how to set up the proxy in PowerShell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used this script with success (from http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/80647f66-139c-40a4-bb7a-04a2d73d423c):

```
#we specify the directory where all files that we want to upload  
$Dir="C:/Dir"    

#ftp server 
$ftp = "ftp://ftp.server.com/dir/" 
$user = "user" 
$pass = "Pass"  

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  

#list every sql server trace file 
foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.trc")){ 
    "Uploading $item..." 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 
 }
```

Comment: This answer deserves more than just 4 "this answer is useful" votes. This code is so minimal and easy to digest. Thank you for sharing this Bradley. The simple effectiveness of this code is what makes it so elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with using `System.Net.WebClient`, but is there a reason why you can't use `ftp.exe`?

```
function FTP-File($FTPserver, $FTPusername, $FTPpassword, $FTPfile){

  #Build FTP script file and run FTP command

  "open $FTPserver" | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII
  $FTPusername | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
  $FTPpassword | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
  "put " + $FTPfile | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
  "quit" | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
  ftp.exe -s:ftp.scr
  Remove-Item ftp.scr
}

FTP-File "10.0.0.250" "username" "password" "c:\testfile.txt"
```

Comment: Thank's for replying, I Tried to use Ftp also, but i have to set up a proxy powershell and i didn't manage to get it work ?! Can you give me the instructions to set up proxy with your Function please ?!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that this was the main issue. I haven't had to deal with using a proxy before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it on the webclient object (also check the properties of $proxy, depending on your environment you might to need to set some of them) :

```
$proxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy http://proxy:8080
$webclient.Proxy = $proxy
```

Comment: The Same Error, Helppppppppppp! plz

Comment: Typo? Wrong variable name? The error shows UploadFile($uri,$File) and your script shows UploadFile($uri, $infographie)

Comment: `$infographie="C:\cat.jpg"
$ftp = "ftp://ftp.something.com/try/cat.jpg"
$user = ""
$pass = ""
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  
$proxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
$webclient.Proxy = $proxy
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
try
{
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $infographie) 
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "An Error occured while uploading file to: $Uri"
    Throw    
}`

I Checked the Code it Works only with Filezila, i didn't manage to get it work with CMD, PowerShell and Curl